# How to display tags of content filtered by a different tag

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type that has 3 taxonomy fields (Year, Project & Type, respectively).

On the top page of the view I want to display all terms of the Year-vocabulary, this is no problem. I rewrite the field so it links to

```
/work/Year
```

On the next page I want to show all the unique Project-terms for the selected year.

Example:

```
Project A: Year: 2014, Project: Scanning Paper, Type: Painting
Project B: Year: 2014, Project: Scanning Paper, Type: Drawing
Project C: Year: 2013, Project: Leaving , Type: Painting
Project D: Year: 2014, Project: Afterlife, Type: Painting
```

If the year 2014 is selected, I want the next view to display all unique projects:

```
Scanning Paper
Afterlife
```

I've been trying this to accomplish this using Views, and been working at a solution for a couple of days now, but I can't figure it out. I've tried a lot of things, searched here and elsewhere, but haven't find a solution. I'm beginning to think maybe the approach with taxonomy terms isn't right, but I need some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can achieve that using views contextual filters. Did you try that?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Yes I have, I have no trouble filtering content on the year it is tagged with. If I do so on 2014, I get 3 projects and twice the project Scanning Paper, but I only want unique projects. I see now my question is a bit unclear about this, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use three views.

The **first view** can be either a view of taxonomy terms (easy enough), or a view of your content type with a relationship, taxonomy terms on node. Use this path: work

If you select the second option you will get duplicate rows, and you will have to use aggregation. You will need three fields: tid (hidden), type (hidden and aggregation set to count), and term name (rewrite it to a link with this: work/[tid]).

The **second view** will have a path: work/% and will be a view of your content type. Add two relationships, one to taxonomy terms on node and select year, and another to taxonomy terms on node, and select project. Give them each a descriptive identifier. Now add a contextual filter: The tid of a taxonomy term, and select the relationship of the year taxonomy vocabulary. Now you will get a lot of duplicates. Again set aggregation on and this time you might have to add fields content type (hidden and aggregation count) as well as tid (hidden, relationship to year vocab, aggregation count). Add two hidden tid fields (for the link construction), one with year relationship, other with project.
Add your link field and rewrite as link like this: work/[tid]/[tid_1]

The **third view** is more of the same. It will have path of word/%/%. You will add one more relationship and contextual filter than you did for view 2.

In view 1 if you do it based on your content type then only years that are being used by your content will show. If you do it as a taxonomy view then all year terms will show, and depending on your content some of these term links will then navigate to empty views.

And when you build your views start off without any sorting on them as this will give initial issues with aggregation. You can add sorting back after you have a working solution.

Comment: I've kept busy with this for a while, and it works, thank you very much.

Comment: Any leads on how this can be transformed into a menu like this? http://i.imgur.com/1kxxkhw.png

Comment: There is a module [Menu Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views). It should get you close. And you will most probably have to use [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) with it, and obviously cache the views. I recently created a complex menu from views using those two modules. I also had to create my own views.view.tpl.php, views-view-field.tpl.php, and view-view-list.tpl.php overrides to get the html right and add my own classes so it plays nice with mmenu (I used the unordered list format)

Answer (score 0):

I have a different scenario for you i accomplise this by having 2 views 
1)list down year using views and using output this field as a link and provide "taxonomy/%" or whatever you like "anything/%".
2)make a view that list all the content now using relationship add taxonomy terms on node and choose you vocabulary.
3)Add a Contextual Filter with name Taxonomy Term, specify validation criteria check->Validator(Taxonomy Term)->Vocabularies(check year)->Filter value type(term name) apply .
4)path of this view would be anything/%.

Comment: I've tried this but then it lists the project-tags for every node, so twice Scanning Paper & once Afterlife (for 2014), while I only want the unique values (so once Scanning Paper & once Afterlife).

Comment: can't you use distinct for that?

Comment: I've tried this, but I couldn't get it to work. Do you have any extra info or care to elaborate? Thank you.